# Would it be an option to get UK visa biometrics after arriving in the UK instead of in the U.S.?

Tags: visas, uk

Like a lot of people, my family is caught up in some argument between the U.S. and UK that has suspended service at U.S. service centers since March 29 for biometrics to support UK resident visa applications.  Some people have mentioned paying to go to a premium center or just waiting.  How could we find out if it would work to go to the UK on the usual passport and completing the biometrics and final stages of the visa application in the UK?

Comment: Questions on residency, work permits and other long term immigration issues belong on [expatriates.se]. However, you haven't specified exactly which visa you're applying for, but taking Tier 2 as an example, you must apply from outside the UK. A small number of special cases can apply within the UK to switch from some other long-term visa. If you don't fall into one of those categories you must leave the UK and apply from elsewhere. See [this site](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/apply) for more details

Comment: You can get premium services from VFS (in the USA, VFS _only_ offers premium services, not normal services). But you can't go to the UK until you get the visa, and you have to give biometrics to get the visa.

Comment: @MichaelHampton think they're wondering if they can go visa free with a US passport then come back the the states before entering on their visa

Comment: Thank you.  We are Tier 2, and it looks like we have to resolve this from outside the UK.  I have learned from my congressional representative that the dispute is between the UK and a private company that performs biometrics services in USCIS government buildings.  So we are exploring work-arounds or hoping for quick resolution.

Comment: @RandyWright were you able to find a solution?